# How to filter out value needed in WHERE statement in self-join in SQL

Tags: sql, self-join

Let's say I have the following SQL table `employee`, and want to answer the question "who lives in the same location as Joe (besides Joe himself)?" using a self-join:

```
| name    | location  |
|---------|-----------|
| Joe     | New York  |
| Sunil   | India     |
| Bob     | New York  |
| Melissa | Kentucky  |
```

To answer the question I could write:

```
SELECT employee_name
FROM (
SELECT DISTINCT e1.name as employee_name
FROM employee e1
JOIN employee e2 ON e1.location = e2.location
WHERE e2.name = "Joe"
)
WHERE employee_name <> "Joe"
```

Is there a way to get this result using only one `SELECT` statement? Not sure if there is a way.

Comment: add `e1.name<>e2.name` in the join condition.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter out "Joe" from the resulting joined table with an extra condition in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e1.name as employee_name
FROM employee e1
JOIN employee e2 ON e1.location = e2.location
WHERE e2.name = "Joe"
  AND e1.name <> "Joe" -- remove row where "Joe" matches to "Joe"
```

Comment: This works, although using `e1.name<>e2.name` is more human readable in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

Do a correlated subquery. Apologies on code, I am doing this on my iPhone.

```
SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE NAME IN ( 
        SELECT DISTINCT LOCATION FROM EMPLOYEE
         WHERE NAME = 'Joe')
And name != 'Joe'
```